# How can I see features added or removed to/from a release of Rally?

Tags: rally

I'm wondering how I would architect something with the Rally SDK. I currently have a grid that filters by Release and Portfolioitem/Feature.

I'm wondering how I could show what features have been removed from a release and what features have been added. Something like:

> + FE123
>   + FE223
>   - FE101

My immediate issue seems to be knowing where to pull the revision info from. Where would I get information to show revision history on either a feature having a parent release or a release revision history having features that have been removed and/or added?

Please let me know if I can make my question clearer, it's a bit of a tough read even reading it back myself.

Answer (score 0):

Rally [LookbackAPI](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual) will give you historic data. You may build your grid using [shapshot store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore) intended to retrieve data from the Lookback API.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. Unfortunately the first link you gave me for the documentation does not work, i get a blank page. The second, im not entirely sure on its implementation with using a grid for this type of store. @nickm

Comment: This is quite messy, but this is what i have: `        console.log(this.selectedState);
        this.myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {


            listeners: {
                load: function (myStore, data, success) {
                    if(!this.Grid) {
                        this._loadGrid(myStore);
                    }
                    console.log(this.selectedState);
                },
                scope: this
            },

            fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Owner', 'State', 'Release']
        });
    }

    }, `

Comment: `  _loadGrid: function (StoryStore) {
        this.Grid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            store: StoryStore,
            columnCfgs: [
                'FormattedID', 'Name', 'Owner', 'State', 'Release'
            ]

        });
        this.add(this.Grid);
    } '

Comment: @VOX. If you have an answer, post it as such, to share your knowledge.

Comment: @TRiG I still haven't figured it out. I absolutely will post when i do.

Comment: If you don't have an answer yet, but do have clarifications to the question, edit them into the question. People will see them there: they're less likely to notice them buried down here in the comments on an answer. @VOX.